# Value does not fall within the expected range in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am doing below things,

1. On Feature Activation, I'm creating a new list with 1 sample row in it.

I'm using our internal API to create a custom list which uses FieldRef.

Sytax is like, FieldRef(string staticName, string displayName, SPFieldType, ... )

And I have created a column like

public static FieldRef SalesPerson = new FieldRef("SalesPersonName", "Person Name", SPFieldType.Text);

1. In my web part, I'm fetching this list's items.

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.ViewFields = string.Format("

IList returnlist = null;

SPList spList = spWeb.Lists.TryGetList(ListName);

if (spList != null)

{

SPListItemCollection listitems = spList.GetItems(query);

returnlist = new List(listitems.Count); //This Gives Correct Number Of Count

foreach (SPListItem item in listitems)

{

returnlist.Add(new MyClass()

{

**_SalesPersonName = item[FIELDS.SalesPerson.DisplayName].ToString();**

}

}

}

And This Gives Below Error :

Server Error in '/' Application.
Value does not fall within the expected range.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: I resolved it.

Instead of 

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.ViewFields = string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}',(FIELDS.SalesPerson.DisplayName));

I used

SPQuery query = new SPQuery(spList.Views["All Items"]);

Comment: thats not really a solution. You had an error generating your query, you should look what in your query was wrong instead of using the All Items View Query